# Sql Azure - remove a secondary server from geo-replication

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to remove a secondary database from geo-replication:

```
alter database DBNAME 
remove secondary on server SERVERNAME
```

However, every time I run that I get:

```
Msg 45182, Level 16, State 1.
Database 'DBNAME' is busy with another operation. Please try your operation later. (Line 1)
```

Can I do this without taking the database offline?

Answer (score 0):

Please take in consideration that ALTER statement should be executed on the master database on which the primary database server is located.

Comment: Cheers, yeah I'm doing that